# Strange issue when I using GtkScrolledWindow in glade

Tags: drag-and-drop, gtk3, glade, gtkscrolledwindow

I want to wrap a listbox widget into a scrolled widget, then I find the GtkScrolledWindow, however, I could not drag and drop a GtkListBox into GtkScrolledWindow. I also tried right click the GtkListBox, select Add Parent then Scrolled Window like the following snapshot.

[image: add_parent]

But, I could make it work by manual modify the glade ui file.

So I want to know Why and How to do it in glade.

Comment: Try adding a Viewport first, then the ScrolledWindow to the added Viewport.

Comment: Thanks, @JoséFonte, you are right.

Comment: Glad to help, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José Fonte's answer is right, I need to wrap the content into a viewport first, then make the viewport as a child of scrolledWindow.

[image]